# Should I use ellipses or em dashes to denote pauses in speech?

Tags: creative-writing, fiction, style, formatting, punctuation

> I flipped open its latch and peered inside. A—gold tooth?
>
> I flipped open its latch and peered inside. A ... gold tooth?
>
> ---
>
> Was it an elephant? No, elephants didn't frequent beaches. It was—a whale!
>
> Was it an elephant? No, elephants didn't frequent beaches. It was ... a whale!

What's the right symbol to use in the examples above?

Comment: It's difficult for me to judge the tone of the sentence examples you used, so I can't give a specific suggestion. There are many uses for elipses and dashes. Dashes are generally more abrupt and can signify a rapid change of topic. They are useful for emotionally-loaded dialogue interruption, because emotions act quickly on the brain. Elipses are slower and more thoughtful. They can be used to show a character stalling for time in order to represent things more to their advantage, which makes them useful for characters who are crisp, professional or controlled.

Comment: I'm no grammarian, but it would make more sense to me if the pause is placed before the sentences in question rather than in the middle: I flipped open its latch and peered inside... A gold tooth? (same with the dash - whichever works batter.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

em dashes are usually used to denote an interruption or sudden change — whether in dialogue, thought or narrative — ellipses are for pauses, again in all respects.

> 'I just don't see why—
>   'I don't care what you think,' Johan barked, turning from me before I could protest.

---

> 'She was just...' His face turned pale as his memory returned to that night.
>   'Just *what*?' I asked, eager for more.

here are some resources: 
[Jodie Renner Editing](http://jodierennerediting.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/how-and-when-to-use-hyphens-dashes.html)
[Novel Publicity](http://www.novelpublicity.com/2012/03/ask-the-editor-when-do-you-use-an-em-dash-when-do-you-use-an-ellipsis/)
[Writer's Relief](http://writersrelief.com/blog/2008/03/serial-commas-ellipses-and-em-dashes/)

Comment: Thanks. I think em dashes are also used in a sudden change of idea?

Comment: That's right @AlexandroChen, they represent any kind of interruption, including an interruption to a thought process or even narrative flow; exactly as you've shown in your examples. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I *might* use an M-dash for the whale example, because it's startling. For the gold watch, that's more of a thoughtful pause, so it would take an ellipsis.

Also related on this site: [Using dashes in writing dialogue](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/6724/using-dashes-in-writing-dialogue/6744) and [How not to overuse ellipsis?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/436/how-not-to-overuse-ellipsis/437)

Answer (score 1):

*Adding to the answers by Lauren Ipsum and CLockeWork.*

I'll just look at the second example:

> Was it an elephant? No, elephants didn't frequent beaches. It was — a whale!
>
> Was it an elephant? No, elephants didn't frequent beaches. It was ... a whale!

It seems to me that the dash as a sign of a sudden change works well in the narrative, but not in direct speech:

> "What happened?"
>
> "I found something on the beach," John replied. "I saw something and at first I thought it was an elephant? But elephants don't frequent beaches. It was — a whale!"

To me, this sounds strange. John is talking as if he were *writing a book!*, which he is not. He is supposed to be speaking with someone. But this works fine:

> "It was ... a whale!"

In direct speech, an ellipsis signifies a pause. A dash in direct speech can only signify an interruption, where the speech breaks off and does *not* continue.

Only in the narrator's narrative, which follows different stylistic principles, does a dash mean a sudden change. Here it *cannot* mean a break-off, because the narrative does not break off until the end of the book. Only if the narrative is written *as if* it was spoken, can a dash in the narrative means a break:

> Was it an elephant? No, elephants didn't frequent beaches. It was— What? No. Stop interrupting me, and let me tell my tale. It was *a whale!*

And an ellipsis has no place in the narrative, in my opinion. What does this mean:

> Was it an elephant? No, elephants didn't frequent beaches. It was ... a whale!

Does it mean that the narrator pauses? He cannot, because he is not talking. There are no pauses in writing, or rather, they take a different form, e.g. as full stops, paragraph breaks, and so on. In poetry you might do:

> It was. A whale.

or more commonly:

> it was
> a whale.

In prose you need to use different constructions:

> It was, as we found, a whale.

Here, the subsidiary clause, serves as a suspenseful pause.

---

## tl;dr

*To sum this up:*

**(a) ellipsis:**

- dialogue: pause
- narrative: — (do not use in fiction)

**(b) dash:**

- dialogue: break-off
- narrative: sudden change

Comment: Ellipsis in narrative parts of fiction works perfectly well, whether for pauses or trailing off. Their use is very common. https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=Ellipsese&meta=&safe=active&gws_rd=ssl#safe=active&hl=en&q=Ellipsis+in+narrative+fiction

Comment: @CLockeWork Please provide an example where it is correctly used and does not evoke spoken language.

Comment: Finding specific examples is way too hard to Google and I'm not at home at the moment to go through my library, but take a look at points 2 and 3 here: https://nhwn.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/grammar-ease-ellipsis-versus-the-em-dash/

Comment: Worth noting that while they can be used outside of dialogue they're the kind of thing that can be easily overused

Answer (score 1):

I'd use ellipses for pauses, dashes are usually used for interruption.

> "I found this - "
>
> "That doesn't matter, look what I found!"

As opposed to:

> "She... She's dead."